# Resizing multiple images with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-resizing

I need to resize multiple images.

This is the HTML:

```
<img id="thumbnailId" src='http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mPlrV_wS_b1vK9avUQ22r9w/140.jpg' class="img-responsive galleryproductimg" style="border: 0px solid blue; margin-top:10px;" />
<img id="thumbnailId" src='http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mIeHLNVqUI1opFM0NmZvH_A/140.jpg' class="img-responsive galleryproductimg" style="border: 0px solid blue; margin-top:10px;" />
```

And my JavaScript code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("ready to go");   
      var imgs = getElementsById("thumbnailId");
      for (var i = 0; i &lt; imgs.length; i++) {
         var img = imgs[i];
         img.onload = function () {
         console.log("image is loaded");
      }
      resizeImage(img);
   }    
});
```

The functions called from this:

```
function getElementsById(elementID) {       
    var elementCollection = new Array();
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for(i = 0; i &lt; allElements.length; i++) {
        if(allElements[i].id == elementID)
            elementCollection.push(allElements[i]);

    }
    return elementCollection;
}
```

And

```
function resizeImage(img) {
        console.log("width, height, src " + img.width + ", " + img.height + ", " + img.src);
        console.log("loaded? " + img.complete);

        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;    
        var constant = 100;
        var ratio = width / height;
        console.log("ratio " + ratio);

        if(width > constant || height > constant) {
            var newWidth = constant;
            var newHeight = constant*ratio;

            if(width &gt; height) {
                newWidth = constant;
                newHeight = constant*ratio;
            } else {
                newWidth = constant*ratio;
                newHeight = constant;           
            }

            console.log("newWidth, newHeight " + newWidth + ", " + newHeight);
            //img.width = newWidth;
            //img.height = newHeight;
            img.style.width = newWidth + "px;";
            img.style.height = newHeight +  + "px;";

            console.log("img from url AFTER " + img.width + ", " + img.height);   
        }
        console.log("==========================");
 }
```

The code seems right, and works for one image. But not for multiple images. The output I get is this:

```
ready to go
resizeImages called
width, height, src 84, 110, http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mPlrV_wS_b1vK9avUQ22r9w/140.jpg
loaded? true
ratio 0.7636363636363637
newWidth, newHeight 76.36363636363637, 100
img from url AFTER 84, 110
==========================
width, height, src 86, 110, http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mIeHLNVqUI1opFM0NmZvH_A/140.jpg
loaded? true
ratio 0.7818181818181819
newWidth, newHeight 78.18181818181819, 100
img from url AFTER 86, 110
==========================
2 image is loaded
```

So basically I'm not even getting the correct dimensions of the image at the start. For some reason the width is always 110. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: can't get dimensions of an image until image is loaded

Comment: resizeImage(img); calling is outside the for loop

Comment: I put it in the loop, and inside the function.onLoad. Same result.

Comment: Note 110 is the height actually and because the two images have the same height This is valid case

Comment: @YouYou what do you mean a valid case?

Comment: You see 110 as the width that not because 110 match the height and both image has same height so that is fine

Comment: The strange thing that why widths & heights less than the original ones of the two images , Do you have 84,86 x 110 after putting on load method

Answer (score 1):

HTML element ID must be unique.
You cannot have more than one element using the same ID

Comment: Maybe add a link to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML element Class instead of ID. Use `document.getElementsByClassName` to filter these elements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in `html` id can not be duplicate in whole `html` page .. and second thing ... you did not called `image resize function` because it is `function's` .. out of scope

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("ready to go");   
      var imgs = getElementsById("thumbnailId");
      for (var i = 0; i &lt; imgs.length; i++) {
         var img = imgs[i];
         img.onload = function () {
         console.log("image is loaded");
         //call should be here
         resizeImage(img);
      }
      //resizeImage(img);
   }
```

});